# Is there a query I can run to see what split a row belongs to in a spanner table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sharding, google-cloud-spanner

I have a table in spanner and I am learning about spanner splits/shards. I would like to run a query against my table to see if the tables splits are distributed evenly across the rows and splits

Is there a query I can run? I'm sure I saw one on the internet at some stage but havent been able to find it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such tool to tell what splits correspond to what key ranges.

The closest thing I can think of is the [key visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/key-visualizer) which allows you to see if your "workload" is evenly distributed among the "keyspace".